# Execute external program from Java (with cmd, Windows)

Tags: java, cmd, external, processbuilder

I've done many research for executing an external program (e.g. iTunes) by some simple code, however the suggestions did never work. Sometimes nothing happend, sometimes I got this error message:
[English: Unable to find "Discord". Be sure the name is written correctly and try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eCYV.png)

My Code is the following:

```
try {
    String name = (String) "start " + table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "cd /D %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/Desktop", "/c", name);
    p.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my example I get the name of the external program from a `JTable`, this part is working fine. The `ProcessBuilder` is changing the directory to the desktop first. Then the external program should be executed by the `start <program name>` command. With this code I get the mentioned error message.

If you have a solution with cmd, please include changing the directory to the desktop.

Comment: See [`ProcessBuilder#directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) for a better way to set the working directory

Answer (score 1):

You should pass each argument as a single entry to `ProcessBuilder`. In your current code, you sometimes take multiple arguments together (like `cd /D %HOME...`). Try passing every argument as it's own parameter, including the command to start and its argument:

```
String name = (String) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "cd", "/D", "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/Desktop", "/c", "start", name);
```

Comment: Sadly it does not work, the same error message occurs.

Answer (score 0):

According to: [cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html),

> /D     Ignore registry AutoRun commands
>             HKLM | HKCU \Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

Did you mean `start.exe /D` not `cmd.exe /D`?

and also they told that

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line is processed as an immediate command in the new shell. Multiple commands separated by the command separator '&' or '&&' are accepted if surrounded by quotes.

Did you mean `cmd.exe /C "cd %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop & Discord"`?